# Finding a value in a data frame on row and column names

Tags: r, dataframe

I got a big data frame that is used like a grid. A small example:

```
   1     5   10 
1  0.1  0.3  0.2
8  0.2  0.5  0.1
13 0.4  0.3  0.1
```

I have an other data frame with two values in every row for which I need the corresponding value from the other data frame.

other one:

```
X    Y
1.5  1.9
5.1  2.5
11   11
```

Which should give me:

```
0.1
0.3
0.1
```

I'm trying to get this done with for loops, but besides that it's slow (I reality I have two big data frames) I cannot get it to work properly.

Does anyone have an idea how to handle this?

Comment: You should create a small example of other dataframe as well and show expected output for your example so that it is clear what you want to do. Don't leave room for others to guess.

Comment: You're right! Already had some confusion due to my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to index by the largest column and row name that is less than the value in your second data frame:

```r
sapply(seq(nrow(df2)), function(i) {
  df1[rev(which(as.numeric(rownames(df1)) < df2$row[i]))[1],
      rev(which(as.numeric(colnames(df1)) < df2$col[i]))[1]]
})

#> [1] 0.1 0.5 0.1
```

---

**Data**

```r
df1 <- structure(list(`1` = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.4), `2` = c(0.3, 0.5, 0.3), 
    `3` = c(0.2, 0.1, 0.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))

df2 <- data.frame(row = c(1.5, 2, 3.1), col = c(1.9, 2.5, 3.6))

df1
#>     1   2   3
#> 1 0.1 0.3 0.2
#> 2 0.2 0.5 0.1
#> 3 0.4 0.3 0.1

df2
#>   row col
#> 1 1.5 1.9
#> 2 2.0 2.5
#> 3 3.1 3.6
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Let me check this. The problem is that i n the real data frame, the rownames are sometimes 20 numbers apart from the next one. So floor isn't enough in that case

Comment: @Lucius sorry that wasn't clear from your question. Now updated.

Answer (score 0):

This will be an awful lot faster than the other answer for larger problem sizes.

```
m <- matrix(c(0.1,0.2,0.4,0.3,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.1),3,3)
rownames(m) <- rn <- c(1,8,13)
colnames(m) <- cn <- c(1,5,10)
pos <- data.frame(X = c(1.6, 5.1, 11), Y = c(1.9, 2.5, 11))

m[cbind(findInterval(pos$Y, rn), findInterval(pos$X, cn))]
#> [1] 0.1 0.3 0.1
```

Comment: The problem is that i n the real data frame, the rownames are sometimes 20 numbers apart from the next one. So floor isn't enough in that case. I edited the question, my bad

Comment: Ah, that completely changes things!  I'll replace my answer in a minute.